# Should I use android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar instead of native one for API 21+?

Tags: android, material-design, appbar

My app is targeting minimal API 21. I see in documentation that I should use `androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar` for AppBar, but it looks like that I should do so only for API lower than 21.

Should I use it then, or just go with default one? (Theme `Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.DarkActionBar`)

Comment: "Should I use android.support.v7" -- you can stop right there. `android.support` was replaced ~5 years ago. If you see something interesting in `android.support`, you should be looking for [its `androidx` replacement](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/appcompat/widget/Toolbar).

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/appbar/setting-up are then heavily outdated :D

Comment: Yes, sometimes the docs do not get updated very well. I filed https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/228527094 in hopes that maybe (just maybe) Google will update their docs. Thanks for pointing out the problem!

Comment: But my question persist. Should I use `com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar` or leave it on default appbar from `Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.DarkActionBar` theme?

Comment: That is mostly a matter of whether you need `Toolbar` / `MaterialToolbar` features or not. If not, you can just stick with `Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.DarkActionBar` or `Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar`. Or, you could look into Jetpack Compose / Compose UI and its `TopAppBar()` composable, if you wanted to go the Compose route.